# Using swagger in WCF services Restful API application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, wcf, swagger

We are converting the WCF services to restful API without extra modifications. We use `WebInvoke` in the WCF service contract and then converting all the WCF service methods to Restful API's.

Now we need to create the swagger for the WCF service restful API project. i could not find much info from the official microsoft website. However i found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio but its for normal ASP.net core API project.

I also found custom swagger for WCF https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf but its not working. is there any sample application or how we can implement this into WCF service restful API application?.

Thanks

Comment: do you want your restful API to provide the swagger definition ? like https://petstore.swagger.io with "code first approach ?

Comment: yes perfectly correct, we need the definition like the link you have shared. But i'm not finding much help on how we can achieve it for WCF Rest API's.

Comment: well, seems that you have pseudo restful api so I do not think that `AddSwaggerGen` will work. I believe you should ask new question tagged with the `swaggerwcf`. But it should be a little bit more detailed and to contain the exact sample and problem definition.